# Spring batch + Complete a step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I having a two steps

```
<batch:step id="parseXML" next="commitSQL">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="bookListReader" writer="xmlBookListWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="commitSQL">
        <batch:tasklet ref="databaseItemWriter"/>
    </batch:step>
```

I dont have any issue with code, but the step `commitSQL` is not executing at all, only the step `parseXML` is running infinitely.

My reader code

```
@Override
public List<Book> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
        NonTransientResourceException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("I am reading :) :)");
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookList.add(new Book("Java","Cay","McGrall","1234"));
    bookList.add(new Book("E Java","Cay","McGrall","1234"));
    return bookList;
}
```

and writer code

```
private static void convertBookListToXML(List<? extends Book> books) throws IOException {
List<Book> bookList = getBookList(books);
try {
    System.out.println("I am writer :) :)");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Books.class);
    Marshaller xmlMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    xmlMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(BOOK_FILE));
    xmlMarshaller.marshal(new Books(bookList), writer);
    writer.close();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

for `parseXML`, but my code for `commitSQL` is not executing at all. Any suggestion how would I come out `parseXML` and continue with `commitSQL`

Comment: Please, use the right tags; this question have no relation with a `batch-file` Windows .BAT batch file!

Comment: you must return null from ItemReader.read() to stop reading process

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci, your choice worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a chunk based step, a step is considered complete once all the input is exhausted.  This is indicated by the `ItemReader` by returning null.  In your reader's case, you never return null so it will run for ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reader returns List and that is correct.
A Spring-Batch writer should contain a write method, and be somewhere in the hierarchy of the ItemWriter interface. This is not visible from the code sample given in the question.

Maybe easiest could be to check the Spring-Batch manual chapt. 6.7.2 for the example on the StaxEventItemWriter, there are also lots of examples for this writer to be found via Google.